# How to stop script from running on a particular page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

The following script is for a MU plugin that loads a tracking javascript on all pages of a website. How do I give a condition, such that the script is not loaded on a particular wordpress page?

```
define('GAUGES_ID', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
function zk_gauges() {


  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var t   = document.createElement('script');
      t.type  = 'text/javascript';
      t.async = true;
      t.id    = 'gauges-tracker';
      t.setAttribute('data-site-id', '<?php echo esc_js(GAUGES_ID) ?>');
      t.src = '//secure.gaug.es/track.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s);
    })();
  </script>
  <?php

}

if (!is_admin()) {
  add_action('wp_footer', 'zk_gauges', 99);
```

I tried  if `(!is_admin()) || !is_page(pid)` where pid is page id. But it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(!is_admin()) && !is_page(pid))
```

Use `AND` instead of `OR`. When you are using `OR`, if `!is_admin()` evaluates to true(not on the dashbord and not doing ajax), the condition `!is_page(pid)` won't be evaluated.